# Unable to access sku in queryProductDetailsAsync with Google Billing Library 6

Tags: kotlin, android-billing, play-billing-library

I am working on migrating my project from Google Billing Library 4 to use Google Billing Library 6. In my `querySkuDetails()` method, I can't access the sku (string) from `queryProductDetailsAsync`

Here's my progress. I am not able to access `skuDetails.sku`, along with `skuDetails.price`

```
private fun querySkuDetails() {

    val productList =
        listOf(
            QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                .setProductId(PRODUCT_ID)
                .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP)
                .build()
        )

    val params = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder().setProductList(productList).build()

    billingClient?.queryProductDetailsAsync(params) { billingResult, productDetailsList ->

        if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
            for (skuDetails in productDetailsList) {
                val sku = skuDetails.sku
                if (PRODUCT_ID == sku) {
                    val price = skuDetails.price
                    priceFromBillingManager = price
                }
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `skuDetails.sku` with `skuDetails.productId`

As for `skuDetails.price`, now it depends on the product type. Since you've requested `INAPP`, you can find the price details inside `skuDetails.oneTimePurchaseOfferDetails`. The corresponding property is called `formattedPrice`.